# Proving $(x, 6) = (x, 8) = 1 \Rightarrow (x, 24) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Hey I was given this question in my discrete math class, and I'm unsure of what I should do!

> Prove that if $x$ is coprime with $6$ and $x$ is coprime with $8$, then $x$ is coprime with 24.

I think I have to use the GCD theorem or co-primality theorem but I don't think what I'm doing is correct but this is what I have so far
$$
1 = ax + by\\
1 \times 1 = (ax + cy) (bz + cw)\\
\gcd(a, c) = 1\\
\gcd(b, c) = 1\\
\gcd((ab)/2, c) = 1
$$
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $x$ is coprime with $6$ it is automatically coprime to $8$.

Comment: Bezout is serious overkill here.  $\gcd (x,24)\in \{1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24\}$ and of those, only $1$ is relatively prime to $6$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: How about you prove that if $x$ is coprime with $24$, then it is coprime with $6$ and $8$, then go the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Bezout we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
Ax+6B=1 \\ 
Cx+8D=1.
\end{eqnarray*}
Multiply these equations
\begin{eqnarray*}
x(ACx+6BC+8AD)+24\times 2BD =1.  
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: no need to use Bezout, use the contrapositive.

- Suppose that $x$ is **not** coprime with $24$.
- What can you say about prime factors of $x$?
- Is it possible for $x$ to be coprime with $6$?

Good luck!